# Qual é a solução para processos assíncronos em PHP?

Tags: php, thread, assincronismo

Em PHP muitas vezes, em meio a uma operação, preciso enviar um e-mail, fazer uma chamada webservice ou registrar um log, e esses as vezes podem demorar no processamento, porém sem necessidade de eu ter que esperar os mesmos para finalizar uma requisição.

Andei dando uma pesquisada por aí, e vi que algumas linguagens como C#, NodeJS e até o Python3.6, andaram implementando funcionalidades de tarefas assíncronas na linguagem.

Procurei por algo em PHP, porém não achei nada satisfatório. Vi muitas gambiarras como usar um *Message Queue*, `fsockopen`, chamadas na linha de comando e afins para poder realizar uma tarefazinha assíncrona.

Eu precisava de algo que fosse possível executar dentro do escopo de um determinado código, sem ter que esperar por algo que fosse construído na mão.

- Existe alguma coisa melhor para implementação de tarefas assíncronas em PHP?
- Existe alguma extensão ou alguma biblioteca que faça esse trabalho (ou pelo menos que simule de maneira mais coerente do que as gambiarras que costumo ver por aí)?

**Nota**: Já andei lendo alguma coisas sobre PThreads, mas não sei se é a solução. Se puderem explicar a respeito dessa extensão, ficarei grato.

Comment: Por favor, não peçam pra mudar de linguagem. Já estou pensando na possibilidade, mas ainda não é o viavel. kkkkk

Comment: C#, Java, C++, Harbour, etc.

Comment: A única coisa "assíncrona" em PHP que me vem a mente é a implementação de client HTTP do pessoal do Guzzle. Eles fornecem um client HTTP similar ao Restangular (JavaScript) que suporta chamadas assíncronas e promises. Se não me falha a memória eles usam `Message Queue` ou algo parecido. Talvez valha a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: @nmindz não, o Guzzle usa o Curl. E ele é assíncrono entre as requisições. De toda forma, o script precisa esperar o encerramento do processo, o que pode falhar com o `set_time_limit`, na minha opinião.

Comment: De qualquer forma, requisições assíncronas podem ser feitas via `fsockopen`, mas não resolve meu problema. Não serve pra enviar e-mail ou registrar logs. Triste é pensar em usar isso pra fazer gambiarras, mas é o que temos :\

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Entendi. Eu estava olhando [isto](https://github.com/guzzle/promises) e imaginei que talvez pudesse ajudar. Bem, boa sorte!

Comment: @nmindz eu uso isso em um sistema. É ótimo, porque o Curl faz uma mágica onde você não precisa esperar por 50 requisições, ele faz uma espécie de requisição simultânea que retorna em tempos diferentes, porém é contato o tempo de execução do script (ou seja, enquanto essa fila não termina, o script continua rodando).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously

Comment: Para quem não entendeu o problema do PHP é que é uma linguagem de *script*, toda vez que tenta fazer algo complexo terá dificuldades. É um caso de usar martelo para um parafuso. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument.

Comment: Gente, acho que estou confundindo as coisas. Fiz essa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208321/existem-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-os-termos-thread-multithread-async-e-await). Talvez eu tenha comentado bobagem aqui :\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma coisa é uma *função* rodar de modo assíncrono, outra coisa é fazer uma chamada para algo externo sem esperar uma resposta (ou pegar a resposta posteriormente), eu não vou entrar em detalhes porque para ser sincero eu não conheço a fundo Guzzle.

PHP só tem realmente suporte a Threads com *PThread*, ainda sim é possivel simular algo. Pessoalmente não vejo necessidade de rodar uma função de maneira assíncrona em um script PHP **que processa uma página web**, talvez eu não entenda bem a necessidade disto, creio que talvez em uma aplicação *CLI* (Command-line interface/interface de linha de comando) que use PHP seria mais interessante, já que poderia executar múltiplas tarefas e ficar rodando infinitamente (ou até todos "eventos" terminarem).

### Chamar um script PHP sem esperar ele responder

Falando independente da necessidade, um exemplo o qual seria algo semelhante ao "assíncrono" (na verdade é um processo totalmente a parte) seria chamar um script PHP através de outro script em modo CLI, ficaria algo como:

```
/**
 * Iniciar script em outro processo
 *
 * @param string $script  Define a localização do script
 * @param string $php_exe Define a localização do interpretador (opcional) 
 * @param string $php_ini Define a localização do php.ini (opcional)
 * @return void
 */
function processPhpScript($script, $php_exe = 'php', $php_ini = null) {
    $script = realpath($script);

    $php_ini = $php_ini ? $php_ini : php_ini_loaded_file();

    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'WIN') !== false) {
        /* Windows OS */
        $exec = 'start /B cmd /S /C ' . escapeshellarg($php_exe . ' -c ' . $php_ini . ' ' . $script) . ' > NUL';
    } else {
        /* nix OS */
        $exec = escapeshellarg($php_exe) . ' -c ' . escapeshellarg($php_ini) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($script . ' >/dev/null 2>&1');
    }

    $handle = popen($exec, 'r');

    if ($handle) {
        pclose($handle);
    }
}

processPhpScript('pasta/script1.php');
processPhpScript('pasta/script2.php');
```

Se estiver em windows os scripts serão executados como se estivessem no CMD com o comando `start` para que não precise esperar:

```
start /B cmd /S /C "c:\php\php.exe -c c:\php\php.ini c:\documents\user\pasta\script1.php" > NUL
start /B cmd /S /C "c:\php\php.exe -c c:\php\php.ini c:\documents\user\pasta\script2.php" > NUL
```

Se estiver em um ambiente unix-like irão executar com para gravar a saída em `/dev/null` ao invés de retornar para o output

```
php -c /etc/php/php.ini /home/user/pasta/script1.php >/dev/null 2>&1
php -c /etc/php/php.ini /home/user/pasta/script2.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Isto fará com que o teu script que chamou a função `processPhpScript` não precise esperar a resposta.

### Curl e fsockopen

Eu creio que quando falamos de assíncrono em *Guzzle* na verdade estamos falando de requisições externas do qual não precisa esperar a resposta porque não a deseja ou de múltiplas requisições que trabalham de maneira concorrente ao mesmo tempo e vão sendo entregues conforme vão terminando, o próprio Curl consegue fazer algo assim:

```
<?php
// Inicia dois CURLs
$ch1 = curl_init("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/");
$ch2 = curl_init("https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/");

//Esta parte é apenas devido ao SSL, é tudo apenas um exemplo
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Inicia o manipulador e adiciona o curls
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch2);

//Executa as requisições simultaneamente
$running = null;

do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running);

//Finaliza o manipulador
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

//Pega o conteúdo
$response1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch1);
$response2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch2);

//Exibe as respostas
echo $response1, PHP_EOL;
echo $response2, PHP_EOL;
```

Agora se observar bem, requisitamos duas requisições ao mesmo tempo, ainda sim para se obter a resposta foi necessário esperar tudo. Creio que no Guzzle o `requestAsync` deve trabalhar com algo como o *Promisse*, que o que ele vai conseguindo obter ele vai enviando para uma resposta em um *callback*, eu não conheço muito o curl, talvez seja possivel checar qual item no `curl_init` terminou, mas irei dar uma sugestão com `fsockopen`, é apenas um exemplo básico:

```
<?php

function createRequest($url, &$failno, &$failstr) {
    $parsed = parse_url($url);

    $isHttps = $parsed['scheme'] == 'https';
    $host = ($isHttps ? 'ssl://' : '') . $parsed['host'];
    $port = isset($parsed['port']) ? $parsed['port'] : ($isHttps ? 443 : 80);

    $socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errorno, $errorstr);

    echo $host, $port;

    if ($socket) {
        $out = "GET " . $parsed['path'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: " . $parsed['host'] . "\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($socket, $out);
        return $socket;
    }

    return false;
}

function checkStatus(&$promisses, \Closure &$done) {
    if (empty($promisses)) {
        return false;
    }

    $nocomplete = false;

    foreach ($promisses as &$promisse) {
        if (feof($promisse['socket']) === false) {
            $nocomplete = true;
            $promisse['response'] .= fgets($promisse['socket'], 1024);
        } else if ($promisse['complete'] === false) {
            $promisse['complete'] = true;
            $done($promisse['url'], $promisse['response']);
        }
    }

    return $nocomplete;
}

function promisseRequests(array $urls, \Closure $done, \Closure $fail)
{
    $promisses = array();

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $current = createRequest($url, $errorno, $errorstr);

        if ($current) {
            $promisses[] = array(
                'complete' => false,
                'response' => '',
                'socket' => $current,
                'url' => $url
            );
        } else {
            $fail($url, $errorno, $errorstr);
        }
    }

    $processing = true;

    while ($processing) {
        $processing = checkStatus($promisses, $done);
    }
}

// Inicia dois CURLs
$urls = array(
    'http://localhost/',
    'http://localhost/inphinit/'
);

promisseRequests($urls, function ($url, $response) {
    var_dump('Sucesso:', $url, $response);
}, function ($url, $errorno, $errorstr) {
    var_dump('Falhou:', $url, $errorno, $errorstr);
});
```

No geral o que eu fiz foi fazer as requisições trabalharem ao mesmo tempo, o que acho interessante disto é que você consegue obter o resultado que primeiro terminar e já manipular como desejar, mas creio que nem sempre é útil.

### Aonde Thread seria interessante

Ambos exemplos que citei acima não são *threads*, um é um processo a parte que evita ter que esperar (já que a chamada é totalmente a perte) e o outro se trata de multiplas requisições HTTP e a que terminar primeiro chama o `Closure`, mas falando de threads de verdade (ou proximo disto) o unico local que eu vejo que talvez ele seria interessante é com um script PHP que fica rodando continuamente, por exemplo um script CLI como já citei ou um Socket para trabalhar com WebSocket (que por sinal também é um CLI).

Vou usar como exemplo o WebSocket, um servidor socket manipula várias chamadas e ele responde ao websocket só quando desejar, imaginando que 5 pessoas se conectem ao socket através de WebSocket fazendo pedidos seria interessante mover os pedidos para Threds e entrega-los somente quando terminado, caso contrário teria que processa-los na medida do que foi pedido e então o usuário que fez um pedido simples acaba tendo que esperar os usuários que fizeram pedidos mais demorados de processar, com o Thread isso poderia melhorar um pouco, ajudando a trabalhar a concorrência (claro se o script for bem escrito).

> Assim que possivel eu postarei um exemplo com WebSocket

### Instalando PThreads

Ele pode ser instalado via [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads), usando o comando:

```
 pecl install pthreads
```

Mas se não tiver Pecl pode tentar e usando Windows pode baixar os binários aqui http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/, mas se usa Mac OSX, Linux ou não tem o binário para a sua versão do PHP e não tem o PECL, então terá que compilar após baixar de https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads, claro que o executável PHP tem que ter sido compilado em sua máquina também e pelo mesmo compilador (não vou entrar em detalhes pois este não é o foco da pergunta)

Comment: O que seria o modo CLI ou aplicação CLI?

Comment: @gato opa, vacilo meu, então CLI é a abreviação de `Command-line interface`, que seria em português algo como "interface de comandos por linha"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, poderia ao menos por uma referência para os curiosos continuarem a leitura?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado fora a doc do PHP.net não sei muito o que adicionar, a maior parte é conhecimento pessoal, sobre o exemplo com websocket ele é complexo de desenvolver, assim que conseguir terminar irei atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento foi mal, eu queria me referir à leitura da compilação usando o mesmo compilador

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso é algo muito amplo e fora do contexto do que foi perguntando, mas é algo mesmo que falta no site (talvez não lembro de nada), talvez eu formule algo a parte sobre o assunto, sobre o PECL eu irei adicionar detalhes assim que terminar os exemplos com WebSocket (precisarei instalar o PECL).

Comment: +1 pela primeira opção (acionar um processo externo), que sem dúvida é o que "resolve" o problema do questionador de modo mais simples. Não é o melhor método, pois pode haver situações onde não é escalável, concorrência, etc., e nisso, o questionador deve também prestar atenção para não acabar caindo em outros "buracos".

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato é verdade, concorrência por exemplo, talvez só consiga com *PThread*, todavia o foco realmente foi explicar a necessidade disto em PHP, em Web creio que isto realmente não é necessário, com a exceção do Websocket, aonde é totalmente necessário coisas como concorrência.

Answer (score 3):

Bem, tudo vai pela abordagem que você vai tomar. Se você espera como `async` e `await` do C# você não encontrará no PHP mesmo.

Não vou entrar muito nos detalhes sobre o que é assíncrono e implementações mais baixo nível pois nunca estudei isso a fundo.

> Existe alguma coisa melhor para implementação de tarefas assíncronas em PHP?

> Existe alguma extensão ou alguma biblioteca que faça esse trabalho (ou pelo menos que simule de maneira mais coerente do que as gambiarras que costumo ver por aí)?

Para esses tipo de problemas que você relatou, podemos utilizar o [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/). Ele é uma coleção de bibliotecas que te ajuda a executar tarefas de forma assíncrona. Ele sugere que você instale algumas extensões para melhorar a performance do event-loop, mas nada complicado para se instalar.

Ele inclui uma implementação de HTTP Server que lembra um pouco o nodeJS

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = function ($request, $response) {
    $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
    $response->end("Hello World\n");
};

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$http = new React\Http\Server($socket, $loop);

$http->on('request', $app);
echo "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337\n";

$socket->listen(1337);
$loop->run();
```

> Em PHP muitas vezes, em meio a uma operação, preciso enviar um e-mail,
> fazer uma chamada webservice ou registrar um log, e esses as vezes
> podem demorar no processamento, porém sem necessidade de eu ter que
> esperar os mesmos para finalizar uma requisição.

Aqui que entra a abordagem e como você irá trabalhar e implementar sua arquitetura pode te ajudar.

Chamadas de webservices geralmente você vai ter que esperar, a não ser que sejam várias chamadas para vários serviços diferentes. Essas *requests* você pode fazer de forma [assíncrona com o guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#async-requests).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org/']);

// Initiate each request but do not block
$promises = [
    'image' => $client->getAsync('/image'),
    'png'   => $client->getAsync('/image/png'),
    'jpeg'  => $client->getAsync('/image/jpeg'),
    'webp'  => $client->getAsync('/image/webp')
];

// Wait on all of the requests to complete. Throws a ConnectException
// if any of the requests fail
$results = Promise\unwrap($promises);

// Wait for the requests to complete, even if some of them fail
$results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();

// You can access each result using the key provided to the unwrap
// function.
echo $results['image']['value']->getHeader('Content-Length')[0]
echo $results['png']['value']->getHeader('Content-Length')[0]
```

Operações pesadas como envio de email, ao meu ver são bem melhor aproveitadas se encaminhas para uma *queue* **fora** do servidor usado para ser seu servidor web. Vários *frameworks* famosos (Zend, Symfony, Laravel) já vem com alguma implementação de *queue* para resolver esses problemas, mas fazer algo do zero também é possível. Segue um exemplo usando [uma biblioteca](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk) para trabalhar com filas gerenciadas pelo Beanstalkd:

```
<?php

// Hopefully you're using Composer autoloading.

use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;

$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');

// ----------------------------------------
// producer (queues jobs)

$pheanstalk
  ->useTube('testtube')
  ->put("job payload goes here\n");

// ----------------------------------------
// worker (performs jobs)

$job = $pheanstalk
  ->watch('testtube')
  ->ignore('default')
  ->reserve();

echo $job->getData();

$pheanstalk->delete($job);

// ----------------------------------------
// check server availability

$pheanstalk->getConnection()->isServiceListening(); // true or false
```

Concluindo, temos por ai algumas opções. Linguagens todas tem suas vantagens e desvantagens e seus recursos são mais um reflexo de como quem usa a linguagem costuma resolver os problemas do que o que queremos.

As vezes antes de decidir como vai ser a implementação, podemos refletir sobre qual meu real problemas e como os outros resolveram.

Comment: Boa resposta. Achei interessante a ideia do `React`. Eu tinha usado o `Beanstalkd` no Laravel, mas não gostei muito da serialização de closures :\. Eu vou pensar nessa ideia de um servidor rodando pra essa operações.

Answer (score 2):

A bibliteca [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pthreads.php) é uma ótima opção para utilização de processo paralelo.

Como instalar:

> Antes de começar, você deve ter **Thread Safety** no PHP habilitado. **Thread Safety** significa que o binário pode trabalhar em um contexto de servidor web multithread, como o Apache 2 no Windows. Thread Safety funciona criando uma cópia local em cada thread, de modo que os dados não colidirão com outra thread.

**No Windows**, procure a versão que combine com seu php em [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads), descompacte o arquivo e procure o arquivo **php_pthreads.dll** e coloque na pasta **ext** dentro da pasta **php** no diretório que você instalou. E coloque o arquivo **pthreadVC2.dll** na pasta **php**. Caso aconteça algum erro, coloque também essa dll em **C:\Windows\System32**.

**No linux**, digite o comando **pecl install pthreads**. Você pode verificar as versões disponíveis em [pecl.php.net](https://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads)

Após tudo estar funcionando, vamos ao exemplo básico:

```
/** THREAD DE ENVIO DE E-MAIL *******************/
class tEmail extends Thread
{
     private $id;

     public function __construct($id)
     {
           $this->id = $id;
     }

     public function run()
     {
         sleep(rand (1, 50));
         echo "Thread: ".$this->id.", Email enviado; ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s")."\r\n";
     }

     public function getId(){
          return $this->id;
     }
}

//Criar 50 thread para rodar
$tEmail = array();
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
    $tEmail[] = (new tEmail($i));
}

foreach ($tEmail as $t) {
   echo ("Thread " . $t->getId() . " iniciada! \r\n");
   $t->start(); //Manda rodar em paralelo
}

//Você pode trabalhar com as instancias delas, mesmo estando em paralelo
foreach ($tEmail as $t) {
     while ($t->isRunning()) { //Pode ser verificado se ainda está rodando
        usleep(100);
     }
     echo ("Thread " . $t->getId() . " finalizada! \r\n");
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: O Saco dessa biblioteca é apenas a "recompilação do PHP"... Estou apanhando aqui :\

Comment: Você possui uma versão do PHP já instalado que não possui TS habilitado correto? (linux ou windows)

Comment: Bem, não sei qual a versão que você está usando, mas nesse tutorial explica como compilar no linux para PHP 5.5 http://eddmann.com/posts/compiling-php-5-5-with-zts-and-pthreads-support/