# Existem diferenças entre os termos Thread, Multithread, Async e Await?

Tags: terminologia, thread, multithreading, async, assincronismo

Eu fiz essa pergunta aqui no Stack Ooverflow:

[Qual é a solução para processos assíncronos em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207775/qual-%C3%A9-a-solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-processos-ass%C3%ADncronos-em-php)

Eu a fiz porque queria que, no meio de uma execução de um processo,  queria ter uma determinada chamada de uma função sendo executada no outro plano, sem necessidade de que o *script* espere o fim da execução do mesmo para ser finalizado.

Conversando com um amigo a respeito do assunto de "PHP não tem assincronismo", fiquei preocupado de estar confundindo o uso de *threads* com assincronismo.

Tenho várias perguntas sobre o assunto:

- Existe relação entre *threads* e essas chamadas/processamentos assíncronos (que geralmente usasse as palavras-chaves `await` ou `async`), que existem em linguagens como C#, Python e NodeJS? Caso sejam diferentes, quais são elas?
- O que seria uma *multithread*? Também tem alguma relação com o processamento assíncrono?
- Eu entendi direito ou, nessas linguagens, a chamada de `await` ou `async` fazem com que o programa termine a execução, enquanto a função continua rodando em segundo plano, ou na verdade o assincronismo significa que a função só não vai ser executada na ordem de escrita do código (igual acontece numa definição de [`setTimeout` no JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94851/por-que-as-vezes-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-o-settimeout-com-valor-0-zero))?

Estou perguntando isso porque pra mim, que programo em PHP, pareceu ser tudo a mesma coisa :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101) é o mecanismo que define uma linha de execução das aplicações.

Multithread é a capacidade de executar várias linhas de execução de um processo que podem rodar paralelamente ou que pareça estar rodando paralela.

Threads só costumam ser necessárias de fato quando há muito processamento.

Para a assincronicidade funcionar não precisa de *threads*, embora elas possam ser usadas em certas circunstâncias para atingir o objetivo. Diretamente uma coisa nada tem a ver com outra.

Para ter algo assíncrono precisa estabelecer alguma forma de tarefa, por um mecanismo pronto ou não.

Em C# dá para entender um pouco melhor a [diferença entre uma tarefa e uma *thread*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101).

Tem uma [pergunta que responde boa partes dessas coisas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101).

A assincronicidade permite que o programa continue executando outras coisas enquanto ele espera por alguma resposta de uma outra parte. Normalmente precisa disto quando se faz IO que tem uma certa latência.

A não ser que uma implementação específica defina assim, nada garante, ou que precise, usar *thread* para realizar a assincronicidade.

Ao contrário do que muitos pensam assincronicidade não garante que algo seja executado em paralelo, muito menos que dê mais performance. Pelo contrário, a performance é pior sempre. Mas pode haver vantagem no seu uso porque a aplicação não fica em estado de espera. Se tudo for feito certo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).