# Como gerir as threads em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Estou a desenvolver um projeto e penso que vou precisar de *multithreading*.

Enquanto iniciar uma *thread* novo não parece difícil, não consigo perceber se tenho que terminar a *thread* ou ela termina sozinha.

A minha aplicação vai, em certas horas fazer um, **ou vários**, trabalhos que podem demorar algum tempo. Como não queria adiar o processo, já que uma das mais importantes partes do projeto é a "agenda", pensei em fazer os vários trabalhos em *threads*. Assim, mesmo que um trabalho esteja a demorar mais, a aplicação principal estaria disponível para correr outros trabalhos ao mesmo tempo.

Uma vez que o trabalho que estava a ser feito na *thread* termina, preciso de destruir a *thread*? Ou ela própria, quando terminar, destrói-se?

O porque da minha preocupação. O programa é suposto correr durante muito tempo, dias no mínimo e se não gerir este processo a estabilidade do programa estaria em causa.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

> Estou a desenvolver um projeto e penso que vou precisar de multithreading.

Então [veja isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101) para ter certeza que precisa mesmo. A maioria das pessoas acreditam que *thread* é algo mágico que faz um código executar mais rápido.

> Enquanto iniciar uma thread novo não parece difícil, não consigo perceber se tenho que terminar a thread ou ela termina sozinha.

Ela é uma classe especial que se auto gerencia e não precisa terminá-la.

> A minha aplicação vai, em certas horas fazer um, ou vários, trabalhos que podem demorar algum tempo. Como não queria adiar o processo, já que uma das mais importantes partes do projeto é a "agenda", pensei em fazer os vários trabalhos em threads. Assim, mesmo que um trabalho esteja a demorar mais, a aplicação principal estaria disponível para correr outros trabalhos ao mesmo tempo.

Algo me diz que não precisa de *thread*. Ou pode fazer em [processo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101) isolado ou pode usar [assincronicidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101). Mas não dá para afirmar sem entender melhor a necessidade.

> Uma vez que o trabalho que estava a ser feito na thread termina, preciso de destruir a thread? Ou ela própria, quando terminar, destrói-se?

Não precisa se preocupar, ainda mais se usar [`Task` que é o mais correto, `Thread`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101) é só para construir coisas em baixo nível. Mas isso é a parte fácil de *thread*, gerenciar múltiplas *threads* é absurdamente mais complicado do que saber se deve destruí-la.

Note que não estou dizendo que ela é destruída.

> O porque da minha preocupação. O programa é suposto correr durante muito tempo, dias no mínimo e se não gerir este processo a estabilidade do programa estaria em causa.

É, parece que precisa de um serviço externo.

Veja [Existem diferenças entre os termos Thread, Multithread, Async e Await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208321/101).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta extensa. Neste momento estou a testar a aplicação e dei conta que quando o processo que envolve a thread é executado, existe um salto no consumo de RAM (dos 10mb para 60mb) e se forem 2 processos (dos 10 para ~200mb) o que, no meu caso, não pode ser aceite. Consegue me dizer se há a razão para isto pode estar relacionada com as threads? EDIT: Mesmo depois do processo terminar o consumo não baixa.

Comment: É provável, porém não dá para saber tão superficialmente.

Comment: Consigo ajudar? Em breve, a aplicação, serve para fazer backups. Também tem um pequeno "programador de tarefas". Uma vez que chega a certa altura, faz o backup. Como o processo do backup demora algum tempo, não pode ser feito na main. Comecei então a explorar formas de fazer o backup sem interromper a aplicação principal. Tendo em conta que a quantidade de backups a mesma hora é indefinida preciso de uma forma de fazer varios trabalhos ao mesmo tempo sem interromper a vida da aplicação principal.

Comment: Nem deve fazer no mesmo processo, *thread* é para outra coisa.

Answer (score 0):

- As threads são finalizadas ao concluir a execução.
  Você não precisa se preocupar com isso.
- A maior preocupação com operações multithread geralmente é o controle de sincronismo.
  Eventualmente você terá várias operações em paralelo e no final gostaria que a resultante dessas operações seja executada em uma thread terceira que deve ser executada somente após a conclusão das threads primárias, para tal pode ser usado o Task.Wait (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx). Você dispara as threads todas e no final aguarda a conclusão para só então (ao concluir todas), seguir com o processo.
- Outra preocupação importante é na manipulação de dados com possibilidade de deadlook. Para tal, usa-se o Lock (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) de forma que apenas umas das threads executará a operação dentro do Lock de cada vez, possibilitando um sincronismo nesse ambiente.